# Changing QGIS cursor size and color?

Tags: qgis, digitizing, mouse-cursor

I'm digitizing some old topographic maps (scanned images), and these maps are in grayscale.

When in editing mode, to draw the contour lines, I would like to be able to change the color and size of the cursor, because the default one is too small, and the black color makes it disappear.

Something like in Blender 3D, where we can define, in pixels, the cursor size. Or in AutoCAD, where we can choose any color to the cursor.

I'm using QGIS 2.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the cursor on the application level type into Python console:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

# action cursor
QApplication.instance().setOverrideCursor(Qt.BusyCursor)
```

Or to set a custom bitmap as the cursor (this might be simply a yellow cross):

```
# customized cursor
QgsApplication.instance().setOverrideCursor(QCursor(QPixmap('e:/icon.png')))
```

To set cursor back:

```
# default
QApplication.instance().setOverrideCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
```

See Qt documentation for more detail: [CursorShape](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#CursorShape-enum) and [Pixmaps](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcursor.html#pixmap)

Comment: Thanks @Detlev. I don't understand much of python inside Qgis, but, is there any way that this setting is made a default? It looks like I have to do this every time I start Qgis.

Comment: It is possible to use the first code snippet as  `openProject()` macro. To do this open **Project -> Project properties -> Macros** and copy the code into the first macro (openProject()). You also have to change **Settings -> Options -> Common -> Activate macros**. As Steven Kay mentioned be careful, since this way the cursor is changed immediately after opening this project.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly change the size of the cross using standard properties. I don't think you can change the colour, though.

**Settings > Options > Digitizing > Vertex Markers**

and change the size value.

Detlev's suggestion is great, although it does affect the whole app, not just digitizing, so be careful how you design the icon (the cursor hotspot seems to be the centre of the image)